# Регулярные выражения и replace

Tags: jquery, регулярные-выражения, replace

Доброго времени суток

Как через `.replace()` + регулярные выражения, поделить к примеру такой код:

```
<div class="na-p_button" id="c_menu" style="display: none;" onclick="$('.na-p').hide(400);$(this).hide(400);$('#o_menu.na-p_button').show(400);">
```

на части, к примеру:

```
<b>$1</b><u>$2</u>$3<b>$4</b>
```

При условие, что 
**$1** - `<`
**$2** - текст от `<` до (пробел)
**$3** - текст от (пробел) до `>`
**$4** - `>`

С учётом того, что:
**$2** - может быть любым (одним) словом
**$3** - может быть словом, словами (т.е. разной длины) и разные символы могут быть

Comment: не закрывайте этот вопрос т.к он не только нужный но и полезный

Comment: (<)(\w+?=\s)([\w\s]+)(>)

Comment: @JavaJunior, этот вариант не работает

Comment: Приведи пример входной строки и выходной

Comment: @Grundy, ну к примеру, все разделения запихать в `<span></span>`

Comment: *Прям в вопросе приведи **начальную** и **итоговую** строки*. По твоему описанию непонятно что ты хочешь получить.

Comment: Для экспериментов с regexp'ами удобнее использовать например [онлайн](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html) тестеры.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 Почему вы объявили конкурс, что-то не так в текущих ответах, включая принятый? Просто хочется понять, стоит ли пытаться давать новые ответы или нет, так как с существующими ответами на первый взгляд всё нормально.

Comment: А почему именно регулярные выражения, почему не использовать DOM (с jQuery), зачем саморезы забивать молотком?)

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр, поздный ответ, но да ладно. Дело в том, что это была попытка реализовать некую "подсветку синтаксиса"..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Регулярное выражение для открывающих тегов (с исключением закрывающих тегов):

```
(<)(\w+)(.[^<]+)?(>)
```

Ссылка на песочницу с пояснениями: https://regexr.com/3q3qd

Пример замены: https://jsbin.com/vazero/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Почему-то код не видит другие слова для замены, но работает как надо.

Comment: А какие, например? Можно без проблем дописать выражение, если поделитесь исходной задачей.

Comment: Тот же html код, только кодов больше.

Comment: А можно пример?

Comment: вот https://jsfiddle.net/CbIPoK2513/xqwjn6rj/

Comment: Отредактировал ответ. У вас появились закрывающие теги, это меняет дело)

Comment: на закрывающие теги используется другой `.replace`, на открывающийся как сделать?

Comment: Так же, как сейчас указано в ответе. Чтобы замена не затрагивала закрывающие теги, добавляется правило `[^<]`, исключающее символ `<` из третьей группы.

Answer (score 1):

Если строго по условиям вопроса (о разделяющем пробеле не сказано, что его необходимо захватывать), то:

```
(<)([^<> ]+) ([^<>]+)(>)
```

$1 - символ `<`;
$2 - любые символы, кроме `"<"`,`" "`,`">"`, один или более до пробела;
$3 - любые символы, кроме `"<"`,`">"`, один или более от пробела и до `">"`;
$4 - символ `>`;